# Which kind of normalizations is better?

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, normalization

I want to do feature selection for a linear model. For this, each feature coloumn should be normalized, and a useful manner is substracting the mean and divided the l2 norm (to obtain unit norm): $\frac{x-\bar{x}}{\textrm{norm}}$.

However, I am wondering which norm should be used: $\textrm{norm}=||x||_2$, or $\textrm{norm}=||x-\bar{x}||_2$?

It seems that the former one  is more commonly used. However, I think that, intuitively, the latter one may be more appropriate since it create features with "real" unit norm that can accept equal penalty effects for feature selection. (I am not sure about which one is correct.）

Comment: The assumation of this question, "the former one is more commonly used", is not corrected. $\textrm{norm}=||x−\bar{x}||_2$ is more commonly used and should be better (in general scenarios).